# How can I turn on verbose error noitify on a remotely deployed mvc3 application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

So, instead of receving the following error on the remote server:

> Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.

I get the following (like debugging locally):

> Server Error in '/' Application. The UPDATE statement conflicted with
>   the FOREIGN KEY constraint ... ...

I have

```
<compilation debug="true" in the web.config>
```

Comment: The debug level doesn't actually matter here, its all about how you are handling errors with customer errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn custom errors OFF in your web.config. However a better alternative is to install ELMAH and log the error and have it delivered to you or view it over a secured page.

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: Note if the server you deploy it to has retail mode on (its off by default) in its machine.config, then you can't override it.

Answer (score 2):

Add `<customErrors mode="off" />` to Web.config.

Beware that exposing exception details can have security implications.

Comment: Thanks, but what web.config (my own - there are two, what section) or the system.webconfig?

Comment: The one in the project root, in `<system.web>`